# Accessing local variable doesn't improve performance

Tags: javascript, optimization

****Clarification**: I'm not looking for the fastest code or optimization. I would like to understand why some code that seem to not be optimized or optimal run in fact in general consistently faster.

## The short version

Why is this code:

```
var index = (Math.floor(y / scale) * img.width + Math.floor(x / scale)) * 4;
```

More performant than this one?

```
var index = Math.floor(ref_index) * 4;
```

## The long version

This week, the author of Impact js published an article about some rendering issue:

http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2012/09/drawing-pixels-is-hard

In the article there was the source of a function to scale an image by accessing pixels in the canvas. I wanted to suggest some traditional ways to optimize this kind of code so that the scaling would be shorter at loading time. But after testing it my result was most of the time worst that the original function.

Guessing this was the JavaScript engine that was doing some smart optimization I tried to understand a bit more what was going on so I did a bunch of test. But my results are quite confusing and I would need some help to understand what's going on.

I have a test page here:

http://www.mx981.com/stuff/resize_bench/test.html

**jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/local-variable-due-to-the-scope-lookup**

To start the test, click the picture and the results will appear in the console.

There are three different versions:

### The original code:

```
for( var y = 0; y < heightScaled; y++ ) {
    for( var x = 0; x < widthScaled; x++ ) {
        var index = (Math.floor(y / scale) * img.width + Math.floor(x / scale)) * 4;
        var indexScaled = (y * widthScaled + x) * 4;
        scaledPixels.data[ indexScaled ] = origPixels.data[ index ];
        scaledPixels.data[ indexScaled+1 ] = origPixels.data[ index+1 ];
        scaledPixels.data[ indexScaled+2 ] = origPixels.data[ index+2 ];
        scaledPixels.data[ indexScaled+3 ] = origPixels.data[ index+3 ];
    }
}
```

**jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/so-accessing-local-variable-doesn-t-improve-performance**

### One of my attempt to optimize it:

```
var ref_index = 0;
var ref_indexScaled = 0
var ref_step = 1 / scale;
for( var y = 0; y < heightScaled; y++ ) {
    for( var x = 0; x < widthScaled; x++ ) {
        var index = Math.floor(ref_index) * 4;
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index ];
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index+1 ];
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index+2 ];
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index+3 ];

        ref_index+= ref_step;
    }
}
```

**jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/so-accessing-local-variable-doesn-t-improve-performance**

### The same optimized code but with recalculating the index variable each time (Hybrid)

```
var ref_index = 0;
var ref_indexScaled = 0
var ref_step = 1 / scale;
for( var y = 0; y < heightScaled; y++ ) {
    for( var x = 0; x < widthScaled; x++ ) {
        var index = (Math.floor(y / scale) * img.width + Math.floor(x / scale)) * 4;
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index ];
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index+1 ];
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index+2 ];
        scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ index+3 ];

        ref_index+= ref_step;
    }
}
```

**jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/so-accessing-local-variable-doesn-t-improve-performance**

The only difference in the two last one is the calculation of the 'index' variable.
And to my surprise the optimized version is slower in most browsers (except opera).

### *Results of personal testing* (not the jsPerf tests):

- **Opera**

  ```
  Original:  8668ms
  Optimized:  932ms
  Hybrid:    8696ms
  ```
- **Chrome**

  ```
  Original:  139ms
  Optimized: 145ms
  Hybrid:    136ms
  ```
- **Safari**

  ```
  Original:  433ms
  Optimized: 853ms
  Hybrid:    451ms
  ```
- **Firefox**

  ```
  Original:  343ms
  Optimized: 422ms
  Hybrid:    350ms
  ```

After digging around, it seems an usual good practice is to access mainly local variable due to the scope lookup. Because The optimized version only call one local variable it should be faster that the Hybrid code which call multiple variable and object in addition to the various operation involved.

So why the "optimized" version is slower?

I thought that it might be because some JavaScript engine don't optimize the Optimized version because it is not hot enough but after using `--trace-opt` in chrome, it seems all version are properly compiled by V8.

At this point I am a bit clueless and wonder if somebody would know what is going on?

I did also some more test cases in this page:

http://www.mx981.com/stuff/resize_bench/index.html

Comment: [jsPerf test setup](http://jsperf.com/so-accessing-local-variable-doesn-t-improve-performance). Hopefully I did it right.

Comment: _After digging around, it seems an usual good practice is to access mainly local variable due to the scope lookup_ In Javascript there is **no** block scoping so all variables in all the three examples are in the same scope (the surrounding function or window); @JaredFarrish At least in chrome I get a _Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18_

Comment: Hi Jared, it would be awesome if you can make it work in jsPerf. I just don't know how to access the canvas pixel information. Browsers are quite picky when you use image hosted on a different domain name.

Comment: I'm trying a `data:uri` instead.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle (so far): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Gme5S/ (PS, this code is awfully messy; that can't be good for "speed" tests.)

Comment: About time: [jsPerf test case (please run to test the code, in multiple browsers if possible)](http://jsperf.com/so-accessing-local-variable-doesn-t-improve-performance).

Comment: A cleaned up fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Gme5S/1/

Comment: Here is a jsPerf test case for the specific two lines of code you're talking about: http://jsperf.com/local-variable-due-to-the-scope-lookup The "long" version is, to put it mildly, whooping up on that "short" version (so says the long version). You need to run test suites like jsPerf, which will process hundreads of thousands, evens millions of iterations, to test a piece of code. Try not to rely on personal observations, as they unlikely to be very accurate against empirical testing. `:)`

Comment: The speed of ++ vs + may also be of note, http://jsperf.com/4x-vs-then-reassign

Comment: Jared's right on this. Just in case you are still not convinced (as you have modified your question after his comment), here is a ["complete test"](http://jsperf.com/so-accessing-local-variable-doesn-t-improve-performance/5).

You shouldn't initialize canvases and modify the DOM in the tests as those have lasting impact on performance. The later iterations are affected by both garbage collection and the (ever growing) gigantic DOM, making everything slower than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

As silly as it sounds, the `Math.whatever()` calls might be tricky to optimize and inline for the JS engines. Whenever possible, prefer an arithmetic operation (not a function call) to achieve the same result.

Adding the following 4th test to http://www.mx981.com/stuff/resize_bench/test.html

```
// Test 4
console.log('- p01 -');
start = new Date().getTime();
for (i=0; i<nbloop; i++) {
  var index = 0;
  var ref_indexScaled = 0
  var ref_step=1/scale;


  for( var y = 0; y < heightScaled; y++ ) {
    for( var x = 0; x < widthScaled; x++ ) {
      var z= index<<2;
      scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ z++ ];
      scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ z++ ];
      scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ z++ ];
      scaledPixels.data[ ref_indexScaled++ ] = origPixels.data[ z++ ];

      index+= ref_step;
    }
  }
}
end = new Date().getTime();
console.log((end-start)+'ms');
```

Yields the following numbers in Opera Next:

- Original - 2311ms
- refactor - 112ms
- hybrid - 2371ms
- p01 - 112ms

Comment: Hi Mathieu, it sounded too good to be true. you re-use the variable i that is also used in the first loop (to count the number of test runs). It's fast because the code is only executed one time instead of 200 times like in the other tests.

Answer (score 0):

Using some basic techniques you can highly optimize performance:

1. When running multiple loops in loops, use:

   while (i--) {
       /* some code here */
   }

... where i is a value greater than 0.

1. Caching variables / localizing variables appropriately to minimize calculations. For larger calculations this means to place part of the calculation at the right layer of abstraction.
2. Re-using variables (re-initialization overhead can become a problem for large amounts of data processing). NOTE: This IS a bad programming design principle but a great performance principle!
3. Reduce property depth. Using object.property kills performance vs just a var containing "object_propertyvalue".

Using those principles you can achieve better performance. Now from a high level, looking at the article you derived this function from, it was flawed in a few ways. So to really optimize the full function instead of just the one line you stated:

```
function resize_Test5( img, scale ) {
    // Takes an image and a scaling factor and returns the scaled image

    // The original image is drawn into an offscreen canvas of the same size
    // and copied, pixel by pixel into another offscreen canvas with the 
    // new size.

    var widthScaled = img.width * scale;
    var heightScaled = img.height * scale;

    var orig = document.createElement('canvas');
    orig.width = img.width;
    orig.height = img.height;
    var origCtx = orig.getContext('2d');
    origCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var origPixels = origCtx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    var scaled = document.createElement('canvas');
    scaled.width = widthScaled;
    scaled.height = heightScaled;
    var scaledCtx = scaled.getContext('2d');
    var scaledPixels = scaledCtx.getImageData( 0, 0, widthScaled, heightScaled );

    // optimization start
    var old_list = origPixels.data;
    var image_width = img.width;
    var h = heightScaled;
    var w = widthScaled;
    var index_old;
    var index_new;
    var h_scale;
    var new_list = [];
    var pre_index_new;

    while(h--){
        h_scale = Math.floor(h / scale) * image_width;
        pre_index_new = h * widthScaled;
        while(w--){
            index_old = (h_scale + Math.floor(w / scale)) * 4;
            index_new = (pre_index_new + w) * 4;
            new_list[ index_new ]     = old_list[ index_old ];
            new_list[ index_new + 1 ] = old_list[ index_old + 1 ];
            new_list[ index_new + 2 ] = old_list[ index_old + 2 ];
            new_list[ index_new + 3 ] = old_list[ index_old + 3 ];
        }
    }
    scaledPixels.data = new_list;
    // optimization stop

    scaledCtx.putImageData( scaledPixels, 0, 0 );
    return scaled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There is a mistake however. You need to reset de value of w for each loop in h, otherwise it goes infinite looping. I added you test in my test page. The results are of course not consistent throughout the brother but overall it seems the original code is still faster. I will edit my original question because I'm not trying the best optimization, I'm just trying to understand why some code that are more complex in a context run actually faster than a leaner code.